# Understanding something vs. understanding 'of' something?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, noun-phrases, gerund-phrases, nominalizations

"Understanding something" or "understanding **of** something"? Is there a general rule? Or does it depend on the context? If it is context dependent, what about this sentence:

> Population growth is a sum of survival and recruitment, and knowledge
> of these two vital rates is crucial for understanding population
> dynamics.

Variant with "of":

> Population growth is a sum of survival and recruitment, and knowledge
> of these two vital rates is crucial for understanding **of**
> population dynamics.

Comment: Ca we write answers in the answer box, unless we want to close this and move to another site.

Comment: The general rule is that _understanding_ can be either a noun, in which case it can't take an object like a verb, so it hasta take a preposition _of_ to indicate what's understood.  Or it can be a verb, in which case it's allowed to take a direct object with no _of_ needed. You can tell the difference by looking for a determiner -- _an understanding, the understanding, some understanding, no understanding_ -- all nouns, taking _of_. Or an auxiliary verb if it's a verb _is understanding, was understanding, am understanding_ -- all verbs, no _of_ required for their objects.

Comment: @JohnLawler — But we can also *come to an understanding* — without *of...*

Comment: Indeed. But the _of_ is required if you name the object of understanding. We can _come to an understanding of something_, but we can't *_come to an understanding something_.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this was an interesting question, so spent some time digging. It is worth browsing the [ngram usages here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=understanding%20of%2Cunderstanding&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). The goal is not so much to look at the frequency but at the actual usages. For example:

> An understanding of the translation of The New Testament

Which is plainly very different than understanding the translation of the New Testament.

> The Child's Understanding of Emotion

Which is also plainly quite different from the child understanding emotion.

However, a bit of a confounding factor here is that these two examples are actually titles of books, and consequently the grammar is a bit compromised. And I think that is a key observation here. I think the problem is that your second sentence is not correct. I think it should be:

> ... is crucial for ***an*** understanding of population dynamics.

The key point here is that "understanding" in this context is a noun not a verb, and so the genitive is adjectival in nature.

So "understanding xyz" is the process or comprehending it, whereas "an understanding of xyz" is the result of that comprehension.

To put it another way: the information about survival and recruitment is crucial to understanding. Understanding what? Well "an understanding of population dynamics."

So too, with the titles above. The first book contains the result of someone understanding the translation of the New Testament, it is not the process of doing so, but the result of doing so. And also the second contains a description of the result of a child's comprehension of emotion rather than the actual process of a child acquiring that understanding.

Comment: Thank you! Are you an English native speaker?